How can I move the system tray, clock etc. into dash-to-dock at the bottom of the screen in Ubuntu 24.04?
I have just updated to Ubuntu 24.04.01 (clean new install, Gnome shell version 46), and I am trying to move the "system tray" (the clock and those icons for sound, Wifi etc.) to the bottom right corner.
I've installed the "Dash-to-Dock" extension version 96 (also tried 91), so the dock is at the bottom now, but apparently Dash-to-dock has lost the option to move the tray that it had in 18.04? I went 5x through the configuration screens, but the option has disappeared.

does this its FOSS article address your question?
